# deselect list method in ExtJS 6.5.3

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6-modern, extjs6.5

I have a big problem with the `Ext.dataview.List` deselect method, it doesn't exist in this version, I'm working in a migration from 6.0.1 to 6.5.3  and all lists that calls the deselect method doesn't work currently.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`dataView.getSelectable().deselect(record);`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.dataview.DataView.html#method-getSelectable) method.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eqs)**, I have created a demo using `dataview`. I hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            tittle: 'DeSELECT RECORD',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'De-select selected record',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var dataView = btn.up('panel').down('dataview');
                    //If you have single selction then you just need to get {dataView.getSelection()}
                    //it will return single record.
                    dataView.getSelectable().deselect(dataView.getSelection());

                    //If you have multiple selection then you need to get {dataView.getSelections()}
                    // it will return all selected record
                    // need to loop to deselect every record
                    // dataView.getSelections().forEach(r => {
                    //     dataView.getSelectable().deselect(r);
                    // });


                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'dataview',
                flex: 1,
                // layout:'fit',
                //  width:'100%',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name', 'age'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Peter',
                        age: 26
                    }, {
                        name: 'Ray',
                        age: 21
                    }, {
                        name: 'Egon',
                        age: 24
                    }, {
                        name: 'Winston',
                        age: 24
                    }]
                },

                itemTpl: '<div>{name} is {age} years old</div>'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

> CSS

```
<style>
    .x-dataview-item {
        background-color: #ccc;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    .x-dataview-item.x-selected{
            background-color: #5c5c;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: It's not part of the API, you shouldn't be calling it.

Comment: Yes we can call because API method is also calling same method in code behind

Comment: No, you absolutely can't, because you can't rely on the existence of it. If the method isn't documented as being public, then it's not part of the API and can change at any point.

Comment: It also doesn't impact the actual selections, all it does is remove the UI portion of the selection, no impact on the underlying selections collection. This is just 100% wrong.

Comment: But if method is defined on doc so it's also provide the cpde source it's not private.

Comment: Aside from it only modifying the UI, it's not in the documentation either. Where is it? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.dataview.List.html

Comment: thanks buddies, I'll will prove next week and I'll tell u the result. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

The correct method is to interact with the selectable. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2er5):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var dv = Ext.Viewport.add([{
            xtype: 'dataview',
            store: {
                data: [{
                    name: 'Peter'
                }, {
                    name: 'Ray'
                }, {
                    name: 'Egon'
                }, {
                    name: 'Winston'
                }]
            },
            itemTpl: '{name}'
        }, {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Deselect first',
            handler: function (btn) {
                dv.getSelectable().deselect(dv.getStore().first());
            }
        }])[0];

        dv.getSelectable().select(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please debug the code it is also calling same method in code behind

Comment: I know it is. However the point is `onItemDeselect` is not part of the public API, nor does it attempt to sanitize the various input forms `deselect` accepts. Nor does it impact the selections collection.